# Focused TextInput not popping keyboard

Tags: reactjs, react-native

As the title says, I have a `TextInput` which is being focused, but is not displaying the keyboard. The input is part of a larger component, which includes a checkbox. When I get a callback for the checkbox, the following code is run:

```
_onCheckboxToggle(value) {
  if (!value) {
    this.setState({
      value: '0.00',
    });
  }

  _.isFunction(this.props.onCheckboxToggle) && this.props.onCheckboxToggle(value);
  this.inputFieldRef && this.inputFieldRef.focus();
}
```

That `focus` method gets routed to a wrapper component for the `TextInput` that simply calls the following code:

```
focus() {
  this.inputRef && this.inputRef.focus();
}
```

The `TextInput`'s ref gets assigned to `this.inputRef` correctly, so I know that's not the issue. If I place a `console.log` statement after focusing to output whether the `inputRef` is focused or not it returns `true`, however I see no keyboard popping up.

I'm very new to React Native, so am not fully versed in some of the intricacies of it, and would appreciate any guidance or places to look to find out where something may be going wrong. Using version 0.51.0 of React Native currently and am seeing this issue on iOS currently (haven't tested Android yet.)

Comment: try programatically clicking on it instead with `click()`, does that work?

Comment: @Chris that throws an error, `this.inputRef.click is not a function`. I've logged out the `inputRef` object just to confirm it is the `TextInput` object I expect, and it is, so maybe `click()` has been removed in the React version we're running?